# NSFetchedResultController crash when setting delegate Swift 4, iOS 10+

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a very strange crash when inserting data from an HTTP Request into CoreData with a backgroundContext using the new:

persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ (context) in
})

My code is the following:

```
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ (context) in
   context.perform {
       //do some insert in this context (usually there is a lot of data)
       do {
          try context.save(). <-- Crash happens here
       } catch {
          //
       }
   }
})
```

My FRC is setup in the main context to provide updates for a UITableView. If in my ViewController I set the FRC delegate to self in order to have the UI updates in the tableView, every time I pull to refresh to get new data there is crash (exactly in the save of the context as shown above). In the thread stack the top line writes the famous:

```
CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:
```

The really strange thing is that I was doing this before the new API of NSPersistentContainer, manually, i.e. creating a private queue context and listening to its save to notification to inform the main queue context and it was working just fine. Now there is this crash.

Also, if I make the insertion of the data from the request in the main queue context, everything is ok. The same applies if I keep using the background context from the performBackgroundTask function but not setting the delegate of the FRC in my view controller (thus, not getting UI updates).

As far as I understand, this is a very simple implementation that previously worked as expected, but now it doesn't and I start to believe that I cannot - anymore - use the FRC with an API that inserts data in the Core Data stack in a private queue context.

Can you suggest another solution?? Thanx!

*The same happens if I use:

```
let context = CDManager.sharedInstance.container.newBackgroundContext()
```

**The response of the Request is served on the main queue.

**EDIT**
I have exactly the same setup in another screen for another FRC for a different model and it works just fine. I am about to crack my head...

**UPDATE**
I commented the code for the problematic FRC, re-wrote it and it works now... Really really strange. However, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the 'context.perform'.

The context is temporary and may not exist outside of the performBackgroundTask block. The performBackgroundTask block is already running on the correct thread. When you call context.perform the context may have already left memory by the time the code is run.

This does not explain why you would have problems with the fetch results controller. I would suggest checking to make sure everything is on the main thread, or sharing that code.

Comment: I have already deleted the context.perform... I have checked everything...

Comment: Also, I tried to manually insert a record from a background context to the Entity that the FRC looks for and the same happened.